# What is the equivelant of "Flashes" for Zend 2?

Tags: yii, zend-framework2

In YII you use "Flashes" to show popup notices. For example, if you fill in a form to and the result of that form is "Congratulations, you have successfully entered the competition", you would use YII Flashes to show this message. What is used to do the same thing in Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zf2 uses the [Flash-messenger](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html)

You should be able to create them with the helper class within your controller like so:

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Hello!');
```

and render them within your .phtml files like so:

```
echo $this->flashMessenger()->render();
```